# using threads with a shared global variable

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm having trouble coming up with an algorithm to ensure mutual exclusion while threads are accessing a shared global variable. I'm trying to write a threaded function that can use a global variable, instead of switching it to a local variable.

I have this code so far:

```
int sumGlobal = 0;

void sumArray(int** array, int size){

  for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<size; j++){
      sumGlobal += array[i][j];
    }
  }
}

int main(){
    int size = 4000;
    int numThreads = 4;

    int** a2DArray = new int*[size];
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        a2DArray[i] = new int[size];
        for (int j=0; j<dim; j++){
          a2DArray[i][j] = genRandNum(0,100);
        }    
    }


    std::vector<std::future<void>> thread_Pool;
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {

        thread_Pool.push_back( std::async(launch::async,
                        sumArray, a2DArray, size));
    }
}
```

I'm unsure of how to guarantee that `sumGlobal` is not rewritten with every thread. I want to update it correctly, so that each thread adds its value to the global variable when it's finished. I'm just trying to learn threading, and not be restricted to non-void functions.

Comment: You have precisely two choices: 1) Use locks for mutual exclusion. 2) Use atomic types and operations to avoid the need for locks.

Answer (score 2):

Make the variable **[atomic](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/)**:

```
#include <atomic>
... 
std::atomic<int> sumGlobal {0};
```

An atomic variable is exempt from data races:  it behaves well even when several threads are trying to read and write it.  Wheteher the atomicity is implemented through mutual exclusion or in a lock free maner is left to the implementation.  As you use `+=`  to atomically update the variable, there is no risk of having inconsistencies in your example.

This [nice video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2) explains you in much more detail what atomics are, why they are needed, and how they work.

You could also keep your variable as they are and use a mutex/lock_gard to protect it, as explained my @Miles Budnek.  The problem is, that only one thread at a time can execute code protected by the mutex.  In your example, this would mean that the processing in the different threads would not really work concurently.  The atomic approach should have superior performance : one thread may still compute indexes and read the array while the other is updating the global variable.

Comment: Thanks, though not quite the solution I'm after. Would you know of a way to implement this while keeping the variable as it is? Though on a sidenote, I get compilation errors after trying what you suggested. Unsure of why.

Comment: @foolsgold This is a pretty minimal change and is probably the very best solution to your issue. Why is it "not quite the solution" you're after?

Comment: @foolsgold i've updated the initialisation to get rid of error message on all compilers.  I've completed with mutex to allow freeze the value of a variable for longer, but I would not recommend this approach in your example.

Comment: Thanks for the video, very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a synchronized object like `std::atomic<int>` as @Christophe suggests, you can use [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) to manually synchronize access to your sum.

```
int sumGlobal = 0;
std::mutex sumMutex;

void sumArray(...) {
    for(...) {
        for(...) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(sumMutex);
            sumGlobal += ...;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that all that locking and unlocking will incur quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the response, these approaches are helpful. Just so you know, this doesn't compile, `error: missing template arguments before 'lock.'` I got it to compile by adding `<std::mutex>`, but the results are incorrect. This produces an incorrect value of the `sumGlobal`, when compared to a non-threaded version. I can include the non-threaded version if needed.

Comment: Oops, fixed the missing template param.  Note that I just copied the function since that's not what you were asking about, but it does not produce the sum of the array.  `sumGlobal` will end up being `numThreads * sum(a2DArray)` with your current code, since each thread is summing up the entire array.  If you want to use threads to sum an array, you'll need to break up the array somehow to tell each thread what portion to sum up.